# Web scraping python - errors while iterating through web page

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I am new in python an I wanted to try web scraping. I am facing a problem with the code bellow. First iteration is working just fine but in second it's not possible for code to take the "Menu" element into a variable. I found similar issue with solution like storing the links in list but I am curious whether would be possible do it this way.

Thank you.

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
enter code here

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://www.mall.sk")


main_menu = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.desktop-menu__item")
main_menu_navi = driver.find_element_by_id("main-menu-navi")

for menu in main_menu:
    actions.move_to_element(main_menu_navi)
    actions.perform()
    main_menu_open = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-menu-navi"))
    )
    logo = driver.find_element_by_class_name("head-logo")
    menu.click()
    print("working...")
```

Comment: main_menu_navi = menu.find_element_by_id("main-menu-navi") Move the main_menu_navi into the loop and edit it slightly. Your constantly referencing the same element and causing a stale element.

Comment: Same with your logo.